# @FormUrlEncoded @Field enum not using a custom Moshi adapter

Tags: android, json, enums, retrofit, moshi

I use Retrofit (v2.9.0) and Moshi (v1.11.0) in my app. I try to call an endpoint this way:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@PATCH("anime/{anime_id}/my_list_status")
fun updateListStatus(
    @Path("anime_id") animeId: Long,
    @Field("num_watched_episodes") nbWatchedEpisodes: Int,
    @Field("score") score: Double,
    @Field("status") watchStatus: WatchStatus,
): Single<MyListStatus>
```

But the WatchStatus->Json conversion is not working as expect. WatchStatus is a simple enum class:

```
enum class WatchStatus {
    COMPLETED,
    DROPPED,
    ON_HOLD,
    PLAN_TO_WATCH,
    WATCHING,
}
```

and I created a custom adapter because my app uses uppercase enum names while the back-end uses lowercase names:

```
class AnimeMoshiAdapters {

    /* Others adapters */

    @ToJson
    fun watchStatusToJson(watchStatus: WatchStatus): String = 
watchStatus.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())

    @FromJson
    fun watchStatusFromJson(watchStatus: String): WatchStatus =
        WatchStatus.valueOf(watchStatus.toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault()))
}
```

I create my Moshi instance this way:

```
Moshi.Builder()
        .addLast(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
        .add(AnimeMoshiAdapters())
        .build()
```

and my Retrofit instance uses it (with Koin injection):

```
Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(get<String>(named("baseUrl")))
        .client(get(named("default")))
        .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(get()))
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
        .build()
```

When parsing a Json to create a WatchStatus enum the adapter is used. It is noticeable because the call fails with an error "com.squareup.moshi.JsonDataException: Expected one of [COMPLETED, DROPPED, ON_HOLD, PLAN_TO_WATCH, WATCHING]" if I remove my custom adapter.
When I try to call the endpoint specified above the transformation of a WatchStatus in Json is wrong and the enum name stay in Uppercase, meaning my custom adapter is not used. If I check the Retrofit logs I can see that it send "num_watched_episodes=12&score=6.0&status=ON_HOLD", so the status is not converted in lowercase.

If I try to manually convert a WatchStatus in Json using the same Moshi instance it works as expected, so I believe my custom adapter implementation is correct.

How can I make Retrofit uses my custom Moshi adapter in this call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moshi adapters' `toJson` apply to the retrofit requests' body (== params annotated with `@BODY`), not query parameters (== params annotated with `@FIELD`). And it is correct and expected behavior, as query parameters are by standards not expected to be JSON formatted strings (eventhough in your case it's just a String). If your server expects the `status` field as query parameter, then there is no other way than to provide it lowerCased by yourself:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@PATCH("anime/{anime_id}/my_list_status")
fun updateListStatus(
    ...
    @Field("status") watchStatus: String
): Single<MyListStatus>
```

and feed your `updateListStatus` with already lowerCased value:

```
updateListStatus(..., COMPLETED.name.toLowerCase())
```

If you have no influence on the server's implementation, then skip the rest of this post.

If you want to utilize your custom adapter's `toJson` function, your server needs to change the request to accept JSON body instead of query params, say like this:

```
PUT: anime/{anime_id}/my_list_status
BODY:
{
  "anime_id" : Long,
  "num_watched_episodes" : Int,
  "score" : Double,
  "status" : WatchStatus
}
```

Then you would create a data class for the body, say named `RequestBody`, then you could change your request to:

```
@PUT("anime/{anime_id}/my_list_status")
fun updateListStatus(
    ...
    @BODY body: RequestBody
): Single<MyListStatus>
```

in which case your custom adapter will take effect and transform the `WatchStatus` inside the `RequestBody` by its defined `toJson` logic.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it totally makes sense. In order to keep the json<->WatchStatus parsing in a single place I reused the Moshi adapter in my repository: AnimeMoshiAdapters().watchStatusToJson(listStatus.status) and it works as wanted.